# understanding why echo doesnt work within a php class function

Tags: php, class, function, scope

I'm trying to debug a class and using print_r and echo to view the variables as the script progresses.

However for some reason I can't seem to get any output from within the function, i've declared the function public but can't get any output using print, echo or print_r.

I'm misunderstanding something fundamental here - can anyone help please.

here's some extract from my code:

this call is from within a public function within the class:

```
$xml_data = $this->convert_to_xml($rs);
```

The method looks like this:

```
public function convert_to_xml($rs) {
    echo "test variable:";
    print_r($rs);
}
```

The print_r was purely to test the values were being passed, but I don't get any output at all

Comment: Does the call actually ever get executed?

Comment: Why is your function call declared before the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return the value to assign it to `$xml_data`, you must actually return it instead of echoing it. `echo` send the value directly to the output stream, while `return` returns the value from the function, so that it can be assigned to a variable or be used in other expressions:

```
public function convert_to_xml($rs) {
     return "test variable:";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're expecting the echo/print_r to output something to php's stdout stream(so that you see it in the web browser), but you aren't actually seeing it for some reason, then most likely you have output buffering on.

try

```
public function convert_to_xml($rs) {
    while (ob_get_level()) 
        ob_end_flush();
     echo "test variable:";
print_r($rs);
}
```

You should see the output now.

Answer (score 0):

Try somothing like this (add some if else statment):

```
public function convert_to_xml($rs = NULL /* this is by default */ ) {
     if(isset($rs) && !empty($rs)){
        var_dump($rs);
     } else {
        echo 'Variable not passed or empty';
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input. I've gone through and managed to get the print_r output as expected - that part was a simple syntax error...

The other part I thought was missing was the output from the variable which was an xml string. This wasn't being shown on the page and I assumed was blank, however it's there when I view the source code of the rendered page

Thanks

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. either you modify your original question to add this second question or ask another question in SO. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

if some one still asking and non of the above making any sense to him
this happened to me 
and it was solved after I put PHP codes **within** the html **body** tag

some servers will ignore any thing that you echo or print outside the body tag